# Почему строки печатаются дважды?

Tags: python

```
for i in range(1,10):
    if i == 1:
        i = (f'{i}st')
        print(i)
    if i == 2:
        i = (f'{i}nd')
        print(i)
    if i == 3:
        i = (f'{i}rd')
        print(i)
    else:
        print(i)
```

В выводе получается, что первые два числа повторяются два раза, с чем связанно такое повторение?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Потому что после `if i == 3` стоит `else`, который печатает строку второй раз всегда когда i не равно трём

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вот из-за этого:

```
else:
    print(i)
```

у вас условия не связаны в один `if`:

```
# если i = 1 выводим 1st
if i == 1:
    i =(f'{i}st')
    print(i)

# если i = 2 выводим 2nd
if i == 2:
    i = (f'{i}nd')
    print(i)

# если i = 3 выводим 3rd
if i == 3:
    i = (f'{i}rd')
    print(i)
else:
    # если i не равно 3 (!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!) вывести i, которое для i = 1 равно 1st, для i = 2 равно 2nd
    print(i)
```

вам надо или внутри `if` поставить `continue` или `elif` вместо `if` ставить

Answer (score 4):

У вас `else` относится только к третьему `if`, попробуйте так:

```
for i in range(1,10):
    if i == 1:
        i =(f'{i}st')
        print(i)
    elif i == 2:
        i = (f'{i}nd')
        print(i)
    elif i == 3:
        i = (f'{i}rd')
        print(i)
    else:
        print(i)
```

как результат:

```
1st
2nd
3rd
4
5
6
7
8
9
```